# XPath query : select only node with unique child

Tags: xpath

I wish to select all `<span>` that have only `<br>` as children :

```
<html>
..
<span>
...
</span>
<span>     <!-- I want those ones -->
  <br/>
</span>
```

How would I select these elements?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean elements with no children except `br` elements, where `br` is mandatory:

```
/html/span
    [br and not(
        *[not(self::br)]
    )]
```

**Meaning:** All `span` elements which have at least one `br` child and no other elements as children.

Comment: +1 More correct answer if `br`s are mandatory. Also, check my "only one `br` as content" predicate.

Comment: @Alejandro. Already checked. May be more efficient by the way.